# How to get the execution time of EACH operator in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

for example, I have a table like:

```
name | height
mike   80
dan    11
```

And I have a Spark SQL like "select distinct name from table where height = 80"

In that case, I will get a Physical Plan like this:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 21
+- HashAggregate(keys=[name#0], functions=[], output=[name#0])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#0, 200)
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[name#0], functions=[], output=[name#0])
         +- Project [name#0]
            +- Filter (isnotnull(height#1L) && (height#1L = 80))
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[name#0,height#1L]
```

Here is the problem, I'd like to get the execution time of EACH operator (such as Project, Filter...), so I check the SparkUI, it seems that Spark records execution time for each operator(figure below).

[Click here to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQSLy.jpg)

I wish to get those results in my code.
So how can I get what I need?

Comment: Have the same question. Would be really useful to know how to do this!